# How to bring winforms user control to front which reside in cell of tablelayout

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a User-control with table-layout and one of cell has another user control which is hidden due to table row as following image. in there, i need show red highlighted area when user touch or type that cell. 
`userControl.BringToFront()` didn't work for me. is there way do this without changing row height ?

[image]

Comment: Not really possible; all controls are confined to their 'cells' and only one can live in each 'cell'. (Note the apostrophes: There really are no cells in a TLP; they are only virtual.) - One workaround would be to temporarily remove the control from the TLP and add it tp its Parent by calculating a new loaction and bringing it ToFront.

Answer (score 1):

In a `TableLayoutPanel`  all controls are confined to their 'cells' and only one can live in each 'cell'. (Note the apostrophes: There really are no cell objects in a TLP; they are only virtual.) So there is no way for controls to overlap each other.

As a workaround you can move the control **temporarily** from the `TLP` to its `Parent` control:

```
private void textBox3_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TableLayoutPanel tlp = tableLayoutPanel1;
    if (textBox3.Parent != tlp) return;
    textBox3.Tag = textBox3.Location;
    Point loc = new Point(tlp.Left + textBox3.Left, tlp.Top + textBox3.Top );
    textBox3.Parent = tlp.Parent;
    textBox3.Location = loc;
    textBox3.Size = new Size(90,200);
    textBox3.BringToFront();
}


private void textBox3_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(textBox3);
    tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumn(textBox3, 1);
    tableLayoutPanel1.SetRow(textBox3, 0);
    textBox3.Location = (Point)(textBox3.Tag);
}
```

I left out all sorts or checks and hard-coded the row and column..

But it does work:

[image]

Note that you could also use the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events but imo this makes the behavious a bit too nervous

Also note that the example assumes that the Parent has enough room to display the larger size. If it hasn't simply move up one more level..

Answer (score 0):

Set `userControl` property `Dock` to `DockStyle.Fill`;

Set tablelayout rows and cols property `AutoSize` to `true`

Comment: as in image, right most controller is a kind of custom dropdown thing. because of that table row height should not be changed